# How do I specify the time between loops in AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, audio

I am making a metronome app, my sound file is a very brief tick sound, so I need to be able to change the time in between loops to get the right beats per minute. Here's the code to continuously play the tick sound. I would like to specify a delay in between each loop of the audioPlayer.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Metronome-Sound.mp3", 
         [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Any solution to this? I’m trying to repeat a sound but with a delay, have you achieved this?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no more api's in iPhone. One of the most easiest way is to use `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` in the delegate method `-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag`

**EDIT**

Simple in .h file after class name implement delegate like this `<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>`

Then in .m file implement the delegate method as below

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to iPhone development. Could you please explain in a little more detail what/how I need to do?

Comment: Thank you but I tried that and I think I was not completely clear as to what I am trying to accomplish. 

I want to make a loop that plays a sound file and sleeps time dt, this loop runs until I hit the pause button and the sleep time dt can be changed via a slider button while the loop is running.